# VS 2013 Team Explorer Section1 in Vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

In VS2013 i see that it has a change log for method automatically populated from TFS and shortcut using Alt+1,2,3,...

is there a way to get this change log shown in VS2010 as well? do i need to enable any options or install and plugins etc..?

[image]thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. What you're looking at is a new feature in VS2013 Ultimate called Code Lens.